# Rich Text Editor on a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, rich-text-editor

I am trying to add a rich text editor in my web page where users can write reviews and format what they have written...something similar to the editor in which we write our posts on this site...
can anyone point me to the right direction regarding this...any tutorial that would help me build such a component...
Also i want a free product....(Forgot to mention earlier...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much research here is what i did...

i needed a control that was free and easy to use..all the editors that i went through came with a licence so i decided to make my own control!!!!

well..i couldnt do that on my own so i used the help of a few sites....

[javascript Rich Text Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299577/javascript-rich-text-editors)

http://aspalliance.com/1092_Rich_Text_Editor_Part_I

http://ws.aspalliance.com/1092_Rich_Text_Editor_Part_II and a few others too...

so the best option for me was to build my own control so that i could customize it according to my needs....

Answer (score 7):

Something in the likes of [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) or [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/), perhaps.

They're quite complete, and customisable.

Answer (score 4):

The editor used on Stack Overflow is the [WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/).

The current version used on the site has been updated by Jeff Attwood and other site users and you can [read about it here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/) and [get a copy of the code](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/) for your own site.

I think you'd be better off using (and perhaps modifying) an existing component rather than writing your own from scratch.

Comment: No it isn't.  You can get it for free.  If you are going to use it I'd recommend following my "get a copy of the code" link so you can get a copy of the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the [Telerik r.a.d Editor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx), and been very happy with it.

Comment: Its not free though; you need a developer license!

Answer (score 0):

http://freetextbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

here is yet another one: [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/)