# Get the highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highlight, selectedtext

When I select some text in the `<div>`, I want that highlighted text to appear in the textbox which is just below the div. How can I do it?

```
<div>
    My text goes here.
</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643635/how-to-get-selected-html-text-with-javascript

Comment: not really, since this addresses interfacing with asp (thought it isnt tagged as such)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KgtW5/ **or using DIV demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KgtW5/3/

`.on` API: http://api.jquery.com/on/

I have customized it for your need man.

Good link: and BIG hint: [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/jquery-get-the-highlighted-text)

Hope demo helps you, lemme know if I missed anything! `:)`

**code**

```
$('textarea').on('select', function() {
    var foo = getSelectionText();
    $('#hulk').val(foo);
});


function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}​
```

**html**

```
<textarea>Some default text; HUlk is very cool innit</textarea>
<br/>

<input type="text" id="hulk" />
​
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: @explorer hiya what is not working bruv? flick me lil more details `:)` will help you out?

Comment: When I select the text from the text area, I am not getting it in the textbox.

Comment: @explorer coleus, I have tried multiple times now working fine in mac osx safari? Can anyone else please check, cheers! **I have added screeshot for details** :)

Comment: I am trying it in Mozilla firefox and Internet explorer. Its not working here.

Comment: @explorer lol ha ha ha okies, Glad it helped! I have asked nbrooks and blaster to reconfirm, cheers

Comment: @Blaster you the man bruv! good to see you around! Thank-you for reconfirm & +1.