# IE 11 document.selection does not work

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to deselect selected content in `HTML` editor.

I have used `selection.empty()` function for deselecting content it is working fine up to IE10 but it is not working in IE11. Also the `create` function is not working in IE11

Is there any alternative function for this?

Comment: Can you show us some code, please ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please take a look at [caniuse][1]


  [1]: http://caniuse.com/

And similar sites, before asking.

Answer (score 7):

IE11 replaced the legacy API with a more standards-compliant API.

> `selection` is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use [getSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See [Compatibility changes in IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacyAPIs).

An [HTMLSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object is now returned, which is different to the old [`selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object and it doesn't look like `empty` is a valid method in the new API. Hopefully the new API will have methods that allow you to perform the same logic.