# Insert text at the caret position, inside a contenteditable body of a frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have an iframe object, and there is a contenteditable body inside. I would like to paste some text, or html element at the caret position. I tried this code, but I've got an error `Cannot read property 'createRange' of undefined`

```
$('#edit_frame').selection.createRange().pasteHTML($('<span>text</span>'));
```

Comment: Where these functions and properties exist: selection & createRange() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you **need get the iFrame's document.**

```
// HTML selected
document.getElementById('edit_frame').contentWindow.document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
```

**But it's IE only.** Read the @Tim Down answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6668159/2389232.

I have adapted the function to get selection HTML for iFrames too. See http://jsfiddle.net/4bp42891/.