# Get selected / highlighted text with code mirror from text area not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

On my text area with [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) I am trying to be able to select/ highlight text and then be able to click on my bold button and should wrap the bold tags around it.

I have looked at

[SO Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) , [SO Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643635/how-to-get-selected-html-text-with-javascript)

But does not seem to work with code mirror.

**My Question is:** With [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) How could I grab the selected text and then make sure when I click on the bold button it wraps the text correctly?

[Codepen Code View](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/mVmxpp)

[Codepen Full View](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/mVmxpp/)

Script

```
var editor = document.getElementById('text-editor');
var string = grabed_text();

    $("#text-editor").each(function (i) {
        editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this, {
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: 'html'
        });

        $('button').click(function(){

          var val = $(this).data('val');


          switch(val){
            case 'bold': editor.replaceSelection('<b>' + string + '</b>');
            break;
           }
        });
    });

function grabed_text() {

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default"  onLoad="text_editor();">
<div class="panel-heading">
<button type="button" data-val="bold" class="btn btn-default">Bold</button>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<textarea id="text-editor" name="text-editor" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div id="question-iframe"></div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue in your code is in the switch case where you're handling bold button.

```
 case 'bold': 
      editor.replaceSelection('<b>' + string + '</b>');
      break;
```

Here you're replacing the current selection by wrapping `<b>` tags around `string` variable but it's not defined anywhere. Ideally it should reflect the current selection from your editor. So I suggest you change your code like below.

```
  // inside your click handler
  var val = $(this).data('val');
  var string = editor.getSelection();

  switch(val){
     case 'bold': { 
               editor.replaceSelection('<b>' + string + '</b>');
            break;
          }
  }
```

Here's a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWmpYd) with the above changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help