# Styling letters of a word within an input differently, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering if this is even possible, but if I have a input containing text, for example lets say the word 'Test' is in the input.  What I would like to be able to do is change the styling on the individual letters of the word 'Test'

I would like the '**Te**' to be bold and then have the 'st' be regular.

It wouldn't have to be bold, maybe I would like the 'e' to be red or something like that.

Any ideas on how this might be accomplished?

Comment: I know of no way to get a browser to style text character-by-character in an `<input>` field, but I'll take this opportunity to plug [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) :-) (It won't solve the problem, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think it is possible (will do some more test).

What about adding a contenteditable div which looks like a input?

Simple contenteditable exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/PpEx7/

EDIT

Nopez not possible. :)

Comment: Yeah I would assume that work I was just wondering if there was anyway to do it within the input so I have all the other features/functionality of the input as well.  I would think it is quite possible that you can't do that with an input.

Comment: Doesn't look possible, dude. Looks like you'll have to use some kind of wrapper HTML like this guy says.

Comment: Using `<b>` instead of `<strong>` :(

Comment: @Raynos: I know. That's just me being lazy ATM ;)

Comment: Is this a cross browser solution though? That is an HTML5 standard (an awesome one at that) but it doesnt seem like IE would support that... Im not sure just asking

Comment: I do think you are probably right PeeHaa that it isn't possible I'll let the question stay unanswered for a while just in case but I'll give it to you as long as somebody doesn't figure out a way to do it within an input.  I suspected it wasn't possible but figured I would ask just in the off chance it is.

Comment: @Mike: You won't believe this one: even IE support it :) http://caniuse.com/contenteditable

Comment: @PeeHaa... Youre right i dont believe it! :) But i did open your fiddle with ie8 and it seems to work just fine... Well well well look who decided to join the <em>FUTURE</em>

Comment: @Collin: of course. Although I really don't think it is possible. I've seen some great people coming up with some great code to prove me wrong in the past :)

Comment: @Mike, @PeeHaa: Microsoft *invented* contenteditable and IE had it a full 4 years before any other browser, so credit where it's due :)

Comment: @Tim: I thought so. But I couldn't find any articles on a quick search.

Comment: @PeeHaa: This is quite a good history of contenteditable in browsers: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at how HTML WYSIWYG editors are build.

Basically, they

- hide the input field and display another html element with the styled content:
  [Highlight text as you type on textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282505/highlight-text-as-you-type-on-textarea)

or

- use design mode in html:
  [javascript Rich Text Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299577/javascript-rich-text-editors)

both ways are not trivial...

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [MDN CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference#Selectors) you can see for yourself that there is no selector for single letters inside a field.

The best you can do is use [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter)

But [As you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/bcTLk/1/) it does not work on `<input />`

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible with an `<input type="text">` tag. You can however trick the user into believing he is using a styled input by replacing it with a contendeditable div or something.

However, I looked into this couple of years ago, and it's a mess if you want a reliable cross browser solution for this. 
Unless I remembered wrong the html from just showing a bold text in a contenteditable div could easily result in the following across the major browsers:

```
<BOLD style="font-weight:bold">Bold</BOLD> <!-- IE -->
<span style="font-weight:bold">Bold</span> <!-- Chrome -->
<b>Bold</b> <!-- Firefox -->
<strong>Bold</strong> <!-- Safari -->
<lol style="fOnt-WEIGHT: bold;">Bold</lol> <!-- IE6 -->
```

No kiddin.

Comment: What about this ugly piece of shit: `<span class="Apple-style-span">` :P

Comment: The markup generated by `execCommand()` is currently in the process of being specified by WHATWG but is probably years from reaching all browsers.